# CloudFront Origin Basic Authorization

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

My origin server is password-protected. I need CloudFront to authenticate with it and cache the contents of my site.

This is basic authorization. I've set the Authorization header by going into Origin settings and setting the Header at the bottom of the page:

```
Header Name       Value
Authorization     Basic myusername:mypassword
```

My problem is that my CloudFront url is prompting me for a username and password. Maybe it's caching .htaccess. How can I prevent it from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems valid.

Custom origin headers are sent to the origin in the request.  If the same header is already present in the request, it is automatically removed, first, then the custom header is added.  The viewer doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have to base64 encode your myusername:mypassword pair, so it looks like:
Header Name       Value
Authorization     Basic base64encode(username:password)

Make sure you invalidate cache before running any tries